# Cannot Run Jupyter Notebook on Terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

for my homework we need to use jupyter notebook to run an .ipynb file. I use Mac and I used `pip install jupyter` to install it using terminal, which was successful. However when I tried to open it using the command`jupter notebook` I get this error. Any ideas? Thanks.
[image: error]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 76, in 
from .base.handlers import Template404, RedirectWithParams
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 24, in 
import prometheus_client
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/**init**.py", line 3, in 
from . import (
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/gc_collector.py", line 43, in 
GC_COLLECTOR = GCCollector()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/gc_collector.py", line 14, in **init**
registry.register(self)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/registry.py", line 26, in register
names = self._get_names(collector)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/registry.py", line 66, in _get_names
for metric in desc_func():
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/gc_collector.py", line 36, in collect
collected.add_metric([generation], value=stat['collected'])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics_core.py", line 126, in add_metric
self.samples.append(Sample(self.name + '_total', dict(zip(self._labelnames, labels)), value, timestamp))
TypeError: **new**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exemplar'

Comment: Do you have Intel Mac or M1? By the way, try to `pip install notebook` and then run `jupyter notebook`

Comment: I have Intel and wow thank you it worked! That's so weird because it displayed "Requirement already satisfied" for all the packages after ```pip install notebook```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is actually what came out in the comments, I'll report it here for future viewers:

```
pip install jupyter
pip install notebook
jupyter-notebook your-file.ipynb
```

See you!

Comment: I have the exact same error but doesn't work for me. :/

Answer (score 5):

From your terminal out screen grab, I can see that you are not in a virtual environment which would mean that you are using global python.

## Three things to check and or consider:

### 1. Python Version (management and checking).

To avoid the type of error that you are seeing- creating dependency issues of your versions of python, it may be an idea to use a package manager like conda or use virtual environments and install within them.

### 2. Proper use of pip install:

If you do not want to use vnev's or a package manager like conda perhaps double-check that you have installed on the correct version of python and install jupyter on the version of python you want to use.

```sh
python3.6 -m pip install jupyter
```

### 3. Environment Management:

There are a number of different options for managing the python version some people like to create virtual environments within your present working directory and active them using:

```sh
python3.6 -m pip install virtualenv
python3.6 -m venv env_name 
source env_name/bin/activate
```

Once activated your terminal will show:

```sh
(env_name) jeffmpro....
```

You can then pip install jupyter inside this environment and this will then run using:

```sh
jupyter notebook
```

If you want to manage the python version and virtual environments globally using shims you can do this using a package called pyenv:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

I would also use homebrew on mac to manage installations in the command line.

https://brew.sh/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions! I will definitely try them. I have many versions of python installed on my computer and it's a headache figuring out which one I am using.

Comment: No problem at all in the long run it really is much easier to manage versions actively. my personal preference on mac is to use pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv, but this does take a bit of configuration to start with.